# What's the name of this methodology?

Tags: uml, project-planning, specifications

Complete specification: I want to to this, this, and this

Infinite iterations:
1. Design a task, module or little piece of software.
2. Implement.
3. Test.

The design and implementation stages occurs practically at the same time.

Does this methodology exist?

Comment: Sounds like all agile practices. Iterative incremental working, or take TDD (Test Driven Development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we'd call it iterative or agile with a complete specification prior to starting iterations.

Comment: but one essential aspect of agile is prioritising the tasks, is ok to say that we want to do this much, but we've to define the most important/essential ones.

Comment: The user could have put any amount of detail into the question, but chose not to.  Are you implying that what I'm calling iterative will be randomly choosing pieces of the system to write, without regard for priority?  Sorry, it doesn't pass the common sense test.

Comment: Relax duffymo, I'm not trying to imply that, just wanted to add this aspect in the comment. :-)